# Cascading for multiple selection of checkbox list

Tags: asp.net, oracle, checkboxlist, cascading

I want to retrieve data from oracle data base for one Checkbox list to another checkbox List for multiple selection in asp.net.
But unfortunately i am getting same ID again again while debugging.
Please help me Where i am doing mistake.

Is there any another easy approach on same.

I want something like : "Select d.depot_code, d.depot_description from table where d.depot in (depot_code from another Checkbox List) " [with comma separated ID]
CODE:

ddlregion Binding code:

```
public void BindRegion()
        {
            OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from regions", con);
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = Cmd;
            da.Fill(ds);
            ddlregion.DataSource = ds;
            ddlregion.DataTextField = "REGION_DESC";
            ddlregion.DataValueField = "REGION_CODE";
            ddlregion.DataBind();

        }



 protected void ddlregion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ddlDepot.Items.Clear();
            ddlDepot.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select Depot--", ""));
            for (int i = 0; i < ddlregion.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                if (ddlregion.Items[i].Selected == true)
                {
                    
                    string str = "select d.depot_code, d.depot_description from regions r, sub_regions sr, depots d where r.region_code = sr.region_code and sr.sub_region_code = d.sub_region_code and active = 'Y' and d.depot_code = " + ddlregion.SelectedItem.Value + "";
                    OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand(str, con);
                    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    da.SelectCommand = Cmd;
                    da.Fill(ds);
                    ddlDepot.DataSource = ds;
                    ddlDepot.DataTextField = "DEPOT_DESCRIPTION";
                    ddlDepot.DataValueField = "DEPOT_CODE";
                    ddlDepot.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the value of `ddlregion.SelectedValue` when debugging?

Comment: Suppose For one Selected Item is "150" next time when loop running for another selected Item its again "150"

Comment: I want something like  : "Select "Column name" from table where ID in (first drop down selected Item ID)" with ',' separated. so that query get happly execute  is there any other aproch to do same

Comment: @VDWWD Please help me

Comment: show the ddlregion binding code

Comment: @JobesK Please find update Question i have added ddlregion code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code again it doesn't look like you need to loop through your region dropdown list. In your ddlRegion_indexchanged just go ahead and bind your ddlDepot drop down and pass it the ddlregion.SelectedValue. So all you need is below, the ddlDepot will bind accordingly when you change the Region because you pass it the selected value every time.

```
      string str = "select d.depot_code, d.depot_description from regions r, sub_regions sr, depots d where r.region_code = sr.region_code and sr.sub_region_code = d.sub_region_code and active = 'Y' and d.depot_code = " + ddlregion.SelectedValue + "";
                OracleCommand Cmd = new OracleCommand(str, con);
                Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.SelectCommand = Cmd;
                da.Fill(ds);
                ddlDepot.DataSource = ds;
                ddlDepot.DataTextField = "DEPOT_DESCRIPTION";
                ddlDepot.DataValueField = "DEPOT_CODE";
                ddlDepot.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am using Multi selection and AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlregion_SelectedIndexChanged" its not working for all selected Items

Comment: Multi-select for a dropdownlist? I think you need to use a ListBox control not DropDownList. Try it with ListBox or CheckBoxList. Can you share your HTML markup?